# Problems installing Homebrew on a new OS X installation (SSL error)

Tags: ssl, mac-osx, github

Have a fresh OS X installation here (new VM), and when trying to install Homebrew I just get an SSL error.

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/': Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:-9847
Failed during: git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master -n --depth=1
```

This is the command I'm using:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Checked around a little bit and tried adding --insecure (or -k) and removing the s from https, but it doesn't seem to help. With --insecure I just get that server aborted the SSL handshake.

Anybody have any idea what is wrong here? "xcode-select --install" has been run as well.

After a post on SO I dumped the packages with tcpdump to a pcap file and opened that with tshark. From that I'm getting:

> 1   0.000000 MY_IP_REMOVED -> 192.30.252.130 TCP 78 49451→443 [SYN]
> Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=32 TSval=170479114 TSecr=0
> SACK_PERM=1
>
> 2   0.128228 192.30.252.130 -> MY_IP_REMOVED TCP 78
> 443→49451 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=14240 Len=0 MSS=1436 SACK_PERM=1
> TSval=2830778812 TSecr=170479114 WS=1024 [ETHERNET FRAME CHECK
> SEQUENCE INCORRECT]
>
> 3   0.128303 MY_IP_REMOVED -> 192.30.252.130 TCP
> 66 49451→443 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=132416 Len=0 TSval=170479237
> TSecr=2830778812
>
> 4   0.150128 MY_IP_REMOVED -> 192.30.252.130 SSL
> 255 Client Hello
>
> 5   0.150913 192.30.252.130 -> MY_IP_REMOVED SSL
> 1158 Continuation Data [ETHERNET FRAME CHECK SEQUENCE INCORRECT]
> 6 0.150916 192.30.252.130 -> 81.26.52.196 TCP 64 443→49451 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1101 Ack=190 Win=4237312 Len=0 [ETHERNET FRAME CHECK SEQUENCE
> INCORRECT]
>
> 7   0.150961 MY_IP_REMOVED -> 192.30.252.130 TCP 66
> 49451→443 [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=1101 Win=131328 Len=0 TSval=170479257
> TSecr=2830778812
>
> 8   0.150990 MY_IP_REMOVED -> 192.30.252.130 TCP 66
> 49451→443 [ACK] Seq=190 Ack=1102 Win=131328 Len=0 TSval=170479257
> TSecr=2830778812
>
> 9   0.151046 MY_IP_REMOVED -> 192.30.252.130 TCP 66
> 49451→443 [FIN, ACK] Seq=190 Ack=1102 Win=132416 Len=0 TSval=170479257
> TSecr=2830778812
>
> 10   0.151156 192.30.252.130 -> MY_IP_REMOVED TCP 64
> 443→49451 [RST] Seq=1102 Win=4237312 Len=0 [ETHERNET FRAME CHECK
> SEQUENCE INCORRECT]

And here's running the dump through tshark -V -r: http://pastebin.com/cZg9NWwF

Comment: Is the time correct in the VM?